# How to watch for the bitcoin transactions over blockchain via nodejs?

Tags: node.js, bitcoin, blockchain

I am using this bitcore npm package.
https://bitcore.io/api/lib

And i want to monitor all the transactions over the blockchain, and read the input address, output address and amount associated with that transaction.

But i am unable to find the javascript method to invoke to accomplish this.
Even i am not able to find a example for this.

I am looking for as short as something like

```
var someLib = require('some-bitcore-lib')

someLib.on('transaction-found', function(){
   // print everything
   console.log(arguments);
   // do something else;
})
```

Any help?
Where can i find that `some-bitcore-lib` or how can i create that in nodejs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't have your own node you can use blockchain.info APIs as described in here (https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-node/tree/master/Socket)

```
const Socket = require('blockchain.info/Socket');
const mySocket = new Socket();
mySocket.onTransaction(function() {
  console.log(arguments);
});
```

You can always watch transactions by running your own node without the need to depend on a service like blockchain.info... For example, if you are using btcd (Golang) (https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd) then you can get notified on transactions like in here (http://godoc.org/github.com/btcsuite/btcrpcclient#Client.NotifyNewTransactions)

Comment: this is great but I can't get it to work on the testnet: https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-node/issues/93

Answer (score 15):

Using a third-party API, as the accepted answers suggests, will work in the short-term. But if you're looking for a long-term, reliable, not-rate-limited solution; you should run your own bitcoin node. It, of course, depends on your project's requirements.

For a robust solution to the OP's question, I suggest the following:

- Run a pruned bitcoin node using bitcoind
- Enable the ZeroMQ interface of bitcoind with the configuration option `zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:3600`. This will enable streaming of raw transaction data to your node.js application
- Use the [ZeroMQ node.js module](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/) to subscribe to the bitcoind's ZeroMQ interface
- Use [bitcoinjs-lib](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib) to decode the raw transaction data

The following node.js example will use zeromq to subscribe to bitcoind's zeromq interface. Then bitcoinjs-lib is used to decode those raw transactions.

```
var bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
var zmq = require('zeromq');
var sock = zmq.socket('sub');
var addr = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:3600';
sock.connect(addr);
sock.subscribe('rawtx');
sock.on('message', function(topic, message) {
    if (topic.toString() === 'rawtx') {
        var rawTx = message.toString('hex');
        var tx = bitcoin.Transaction.fromHex(rawTx);
        var txid = tx.getId();
        tx.ins = tx.ins.map(function(in) {
            in.address = bitcoin.address.fromOutputScript(in.script, bitcoin.networks.bitcoin);
            return in;
        });
        tx.outs = tx.outs.map(function(out) {
            out.address = bitcoin.address.fromOutputScript(out.script, bitcoin.networks.bitcoin);
            return out;
        });
        console.log('received transaction', txid, tx);
    }
});
```

For more details, please have a look at [this guide](https://degreesofzero.com/article/streaming-transactions-from-bitcoind-via-zeromq.html)

Comment: Hello is there any library to help with it , i have been trying bitcore
but it is very confusing with there libraries 
bitcore 
then bitcore-node
can you suggest anything else?

Comment: BTW this is better solution.

Comment: Great answer, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I think [this](https://bitcoindev.network/accessing-bitcoins-zeromq-interface/) is what you're looking for. The tutorial helps the user set up a local btc node and demonstrates how to use a zmq subscription along with RPC comms to accomplish sending and receiving transactions as well as notifications and other functionality.

@c.hill's response is correct but leaves out the more complicated functionality described here :)